# Upgrading from .net core 2.1 to .net 5.0 error 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseDatabaseErrorPage'

Tags: .net-5, asp.net5

Can anyone recommend solution for below error getting when Upgrading from .net core 2.1 to .net 5.0 :

'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseDatabaseErrorPage' and no accessible extension method 'UseDatabaseErrorPage' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Microsoft Doc says its obsolete:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.databaseerrorpageextensions.usedatabaseerrorpage?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Below reference from microsoft page does not work on 5.0:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/432

Thanks,

Comment: Try Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore library.

Comment: @ChinmayT Already tried, it says The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics'.

Comment: @ChinmayT thanks, that was the to be added from NuGet.

Comment: I have tried to add an answer showing the same but by the time you figure it out. Please accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore`

[image]
2. Add using statement `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore`

3. Add middleware  `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`